# IE10 specific issue with a jQuery overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I've got a pretty bizarre problem with my code - it works fine in ALL browsers apart from IE10. It's working great in IE8 and 9.

The code causes an overlay to appear on the page when a button is clicked (class ".modal").

However, in IE 10, when the button is clicked, the overlay appears from a brief second, and then the browser navigates to a blank white page.

The code is below - unfortunately I cannot provide a fiddle or the HTML because the links are from an internal corporate testing environment. Because of that, I'm hoping more that someone has encountered a similar problem with IE 10 behaving differently to IE 9 with regard to anything suspect in the code below. Any ideas appreciated, I've been trying all day.

I wondered if the initial e.preventDefault was at fault, and replaced it with e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
but no luck there.

```
/* Overlay links - open a modal window */
$('.modal').live('click', function (e) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    popUp(link + '&ajaxFetch=true');
});


/* Popup overlay */
function popUp(link) {
//alert works here
$.fn.colorbox ({
    href: link + "&ajaxOverlay=true",
    initialWidth: 800,
    width: 800,
    maxHeight:500,
    transistion: "elastic",
    rel: "nofollow",
    title: true,
    scrolling: false,
    fixed:true,
    close: "Close this window",
    onComplete: function () {
        $('<a href="#" class="cboxClose">Close</a>').appendTo('.overlayContainer .buttonsContainer');
        popUpShowRelevantSectionFromId(link);
        $('.overlayContainer').jScrollPane({keyboardSpeed:10,animateScroll: true});
        //Adding gradient divs to overlay window
        if($("#cboxLoadedContent").length){
            $(".overlayContainer").append("<div class='gradientTop'></div>");
            $(".overlayContainer").append("<div class='gradientBottom'></div>");
        }
    }
});
}

//I'm just adding the rest in for completeness - at this point the new window has already opened and the white screen appeared.

/* Popup overlay - show only relevant section (using "id" in querystring) */
function popUpShowRelevantSectionFromId(url) {
var sectionId = "#" + getQueryStringValueFromQueryStringKey(url, "id");
if ($(sectionId).length) {
    //reSizePopUp(sectionId);
    showOnlyRelevantSection(sectionId);
    s.pageName = pagename_substeps+':'+getQueryStringValueFromQueryStringKey(url, "id");
    s.t();
   }
}

    /* Popup overlay - popUpShowRelevantSectionFromId - helper returns query string value     from a specified url for a specified key */

function getQueryStringValueFromQueryStringKey(url, key) {
var queryStringValue;
var urlSections = url.split("?");
if (urlSections.length == 2) {
    var queryStringItems = urlSections[1].split("&");
    key = key + "=";
    $.each(queryStringItems, function (index, queryStringItem) {
        if (queryStringItem.indexOf(key) > -1) {
            queryStringValue = queryStringItem.split("=")[1];
            return;
        }
    });
}
return queryStringValue;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that `e.preventDefault` check because jQuery normalizes the behavior between browsers to be consistent by calling a custom Event object's `preventDefault` (what `e` is in your jQuery event handler). Have you watched IE's Developer Tools to look for any exceptions?